# A function that depends on initial conditions that changes everytime

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve a quantity $r$ with respect to a quantity $Q$. Now, $r$ is in terms of the variables that I need to solve from the set of differential equations that I listed inside the NDSolve, but of course I would need initial conditions. Here's the tricky part, the initial condition $y[0]$ should be tuned as $Q$ varies in order to assure that some parameter, let's call it $N$ is fixed at some value, say $N=60$.

So the DE's are listed in NDSolve. Some of the differential equations/equations that I need to solve depends on the parameter $Q$ which I should vary from 1 to 100. So, I should choose a $Q$ say, $Q=10$ and find a proper initial condition $y[0]$. I will do this 100 times, from 1 to 100.

Now, $N=\int H dt~$ so I wrote a code and set it equal to "ndsol[a_,b_]". Next, I plotted $N$ with respect to the time of calculation $tfin$; in this plot, I need to vary the initial condition $y[0]$ so that $N=60$ as the calculation time $tfin$ ends. Note: Don't bother with the initial condition $y'[0]$ since the DE's are not very sensitive to it, it's just there in case I need to tweak it.

```
Mp = 2.4353*10^18;
m = 1.8*10^13;
Rm = (1.8*10^13)/(2.4353*10^18);
tfin = 10^7; 
sol[a_, b_] := NDSolve[{dy'[t] + 3 H[t] (1 + Q=10) dy[t] + Rm^2 y[t] == 0, H[t] == Sqrt[(0.5 dy[t]^2 + 0.5 Rm^2 y[t]^2 + \[Rho][t])/3], \[Rho]'[t] + 4 H[t] \[Rho][t] == 3 H[t] (Q=10) dy[t]^2, y'[t] == dy[t], y[0] == -a, dy[0] == b, \[Rho][0] == Rm^4}, {y, dy, H, \[Rho]}, {t, 0, tfin}]
sol[1, 1/100000]
H[z] == Sqrt[(0.5 dy[t]^2 + 0.5 Rm^2 y[t]^2 + \[Rho][t])/3]
ndsol[a_, b_] := NDSolve[{D[N1x[z], z] == Evaluate[H[z] /. First@sol[a, b]], N1x[0] == 0}, N1x, {z, 0, tfin}]
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[N1x[x] /. First@ndsol[a, b]], {x, 0, tfin}], {{a, 1}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{b, 1/100000}, 0, 0.00009, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Now, suppose I have chosen the desired initial condition $y[0]=-40$, onto the quantity that I want to calculate, $r$ vs $Q$.

```
Mp = 2.4353*10^18;
m = 1.8*10^13;
Rm = (1.8*10^13)/(2.4353*10^18);
tfin = 10^7; 
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{dy'[t] + 3 H[t] (1 + Q) dy[t] + Rm^2 y[t] == 0, H[t] == Sqrt[(0.5 dy[t]^2 + 0.5 Rm^2 y[t]^2 + \[Rho][t])/3], \[Rho]'[t] + 4 H[t] \[Rho][t] == 3 H[t] Q dy[t]^2, y'[t] == dy[t], y[0] == -40, dy[0] == 9*10^-6, \[Rho][0] == Rm^4}, {y, dy, H, \[Rho]}, {t, 0, tfin},{Q}]
ysol[Q_] := y[Q][t] /. sol;
ypsol[Q_] := dy[Q][t] /. sol;
Hsol[Q_] := H[Q][t] /. sol;
\[Rho]sol[Q_] := \[Rho][Q][t] /. sol;
r[Q_]:= some expression in terms of ysol, ypsol, Hsol, \Rhosol
Evaluate[r[10] /. t -> 10^7]
```

Done, I repeat it again 99 times for the other $Q$ values. My question is, isn't there any way to do this in an easier way? Or maybe there is a way to fix $N=60$ and and not worry about the initial conditions? Or any suggestions on how to tackle this problem more efficiently?

Comment: `Table[r[Q] /. t -> 10^7, {Q, 0, 10}]`

Comment: @MMM The initial conditions should be changed/modified every time it doesn't satisfy N=60, so I think what you suggested applies only if I don't need to change the initial conditions.